# Blender cycles, samples color

Tags: colors, render, blender, sample, cpu-cycles

I am trying to collect from Cycles source code, the color of each sample during the rendering algorithm. However, after 2 months of research (...), I still don't understand how to get them.

I've been looking at the *device_cpu.cpp* file and in particular at the path_trace() function.

When looking at the render_buffer variable, and printing its content, it doesn't seem to store the samples' color: I write the value in a .txt file (samplesOutput) writing the following line

```
 void path_trace(DeviceTask &task, RenderTile &tile, KernelGlobals *kg)
 {
            float *render_buffer = (float*)tile.buffer;
            int start_sample = tile.start_sample;
            int end_sample = tile.start_sample + tile.num_samples;

            for(int sample = start_sample; sample < end_sample; sample++) {
                if(task.get_cancel() || task_pool.canceled()) {
                    if(task.need_finish_queue == false)
                        break;
                }

                for(int y = tile.y; y < tile.y + tile.h; y++) {
                    for(int x = tile.x; x < tile.x + tile.w; x++) {
                        path_trace_kernel()(kg, render_buffer,
                                            sample, x, y, tile.offset,
                                            tile.stride);
                        int step = tile.offset + x + y*tile.stride;
                        step *= kernel_data.film.pass_stride;
                        samplesOutput << x << " " << y << " " << *(render_buffer + step) << " "
                                << *(render_buffer + step + 1) << " " << *(render_buffer + step + 2) << " "
                                << *(render_buffer + step + 3) << " " << std::endl;

            task.update_progress(&tile, tile.w*tile.h);
        }
}
```

Here is an extract of what I get for [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bwHg.png)

```
25 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
26 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
27 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 

28 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
1 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
1 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
29 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
2 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
2 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
30 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
3 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
3 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
31 2 0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1 
4 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13 
4 164 0.661389 0.661389 0.661389 13
...
```

The color of the cube is rgba(0.8, 0, 0.8, 1.0).

I figured out that (0.0508761 0.0508761 0.0508761 1) is the color of the background (gray).

What is weird, is the 4th value which I expected to be alpha but I get 13 which greater than 1.

Any clue  how where to look at to get those samples' color ?

Thanks

Comment: The lights and environment all alter the surface colour of the object, so don't expect to see 0.8,0.8,1.0. My first guess for the fourth value would be z-depth (as in distance from camera). What pass is being rendered when you see those values? Many passes are calculated (which are available in render layers) and then the final image is a composition of all of them. I think [this cgcookie tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq5YWSpvME8) best explains how they are combined. I expect alpha will be the amount of environment visible, provided you have transparent background enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sambler ! Things are clearer now, you managed to solve my problem.